# Can I develop RMI solutions for the blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, rmi

I would like to develop a RMI-based application on my blackberry. But I notice some of the key remoting types (like UnicastRemoteObject and java.rmi.registry.*) aren't defined.
Is there a way around this, for example like some other library I can use to build out  my solution?

Comment: OK, so on the face of it, the answer seems to be no (at least from a Sun MIDP perspective): http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/socketRMI/

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this at this time - see http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/socketRMI/